# How to connect to WiFi without using password?

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-router

In case, i forget my WiFi Password, then except from changing password from Localhost address, there is any other way to connect to WiFi?

Comment: [Reveal WiFi passwords on Windows](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/view-saved-wifi-passwords-windows/)

Comment: A RADIUS server could be configured, however the easiest solution is what @Alex suggested and simply use one of the many programs that exist to reveal the WiFi password saved in your user's credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can connect to locked WiFi Without password by using the functionality of WPS (WiFi Protected Set Up). Most of the Routers support WPS function. For this trick, you must have physical access to the Router of WiFi network you want to connect to. If you are on Windows or Android device, then you are lucky, this trick will gonna work for you. Because Apple Ecosystem doesn’t support the WPS function.

You can do this in simple steps:

Step 1: Go to “Settings” in your Smartphone –> “WiFi” –> Go to “More” or “3 Vertical dot icon” and search for “WPS Push Button” option and just Tap on it.

Step 2: Now, Also Tap the “WPS” button on the backside of your Router. Within some seconds these both devices pair up and your device will connect to WiFi network. That’s It!!!

Try it.

**[Source Reference]:** [How to Connect to Locked WiFi Without using Password](https://www.mashnol.org/how-to-connect-to-locked-wifi-without-password/)

Comment: Thanks Sneha. I tried this method and it really worked. This is the way i was looking for.

Comment: WPS is insecure. Here's why: https://www.howtogeek.com/176124/wi-fi-protected-setup-wps-is-insecure-heres-why-you-should-disable-it/ . If unavoidable use it to connect then disable it.

Comment: WPS should _never_ be used nor enabled on a router... While technically answering the OP's question, this answer contains no warning of the fact WPS is not remotely secure and thus should never be utilized, regardless of circumstance.

Answer (score -1):

Features Of The WPS
WPS can streamline the connection process. Here’s [how WPS connections can be completed](https://modernfury.us/what-is-wps/):

To turn on the discovery of the new gadgets push the WPS button on your router. Then go to the device and choose the network that you intend to connect to. The gadget will be automatically connected to the wireless network without inputting the network password.
Some wireless devices like wireless printers or range extenders may have their own WPS button. You can use that for making quick connections. You can easily connect those devices to your network system by just pressing the WPS buttons respectively in the router and the devices. There is no need to input any data during the process. WPS sends the network password automatically to the devices ant their setting will remember the password. You don’t need to use the WPS buttons again as they will able to connect the same network spontaneously.
There is also a method that involves the use of an 8-digit PIN. All WPS enabled router have an automatically generated PIN. This PIN cannot be changed by the users. The PIN can be found on the WPS configuration page on the router. Some devices that don’t have the WPS button will ask for the PIN with its WPS support. After entering the PIN, they will authenticate themselves and will connect to the wireless network.
The last method is also the involvement of an 8-digit PIN. The devices that don’t have the WPS button will generate a client PIN with its WPS support. You have to enter the PIN in the router’s wireless configuration panels. The router will use the PIN to add the device to the network.
The first of the two methods are very quick, but the last two can take a lot of time.

Comment: WPS should never be used nor enabled on a router... While technically answering the OP's question, this answer contains no warning of the fact WPS is not remotely secure and thus should never be utilized, regardless of circumstance.